# How to merge element of an array where a key value match

Tags: php, arrays

I Have an array in that array i want to merge element but the condition is if Key "HotelCode" match with another element's "HotelCode" Then merge otherwise left it. 
 
 **MyArray**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC01
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 200
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC02
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 210
                        )
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC03
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 220
                        )
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC04
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 230
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC02
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 310
                        )
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC01
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 300
                        )
                )



            [2] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC03
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 320
                        )
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC04
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 330
                        )
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC03
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 420
                        )
                )  

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC01
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 400
                        )
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [HotelCode] => ASSOC02
                    [Price] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 410
                        )
                )

        )
)
```

**For Example:**

In **MyArray** there is multiple array that array i want to into on array, but the condition is i have to check **HotelCode** key value is matching or not if it is matching then keep it otherwise left it.

**Like Below Array**:

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [HotelCode] => ASSOC01
            [Room] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 200
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 300
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 400
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HotelCode] => ASSOC02
            [Room] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 210
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 310
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 410
                        )
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [HotelCode] => ASSOC03
            [Room] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 220
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 320
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [RoomPrice] => 420
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**In above array you can see what i did.**

```
MyArray[0][0][HotelCode], MyArray[1][1][HotelCode] and MyArray[2][1][HotelCode] values are same then i kept in an array
```

**But as you can see**

```
MyArray[0][3][HotelCode] and MyArray[1][3][HotelCode] are same but that "HotelCode" value is not available in MyArray[2] than i just left it.
```

Comment: Array_merge is for you

Comment: do i need to foreach with array_merge() because i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
$array = array(...); // Your MyArray data
$Temp_array = [];
// Merging array here 
foreach($array as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        $Temp_array[$value1['HotelCode']][$key1] = $value1;
        $Temp_array[$value1['HotelCode']]['Room'][] = $value1['Price'];
        unset($Temp_array[$value1['HotelCode']]['Price']);
    }
}

$Temp_array2 = array_values($Temp_array);

// Removing Incompete array Here 
$Final_Result_Array = [];

foreach ($Temp_array2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    if (count($array) == count($value1['Room'])) {
        $Final_Result_Array[] = $value2;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($Final_Result_Array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your question is, but if you just want to build an array in which the room prices are grouped by hotel code, then you can do this:

```
$data = ...; // The original MyArray data
$mergedData = [];

foreach($data as $hotelPrices) {
    foreach($hotelPrices as $roomPrice) {
        $hotelCode = $roomPrice['HotelCode'];
        $mergedData[$hotelCode]['HotelCode'] = $hotelCode;
        $mergedData[$hotelCode]['Room'][] = $roomPrice['Price'];
    }
}

// If the array must be numerically indexed
$numericIndexedData = array_values($mergedData);
```

This code builds a new array indexed by `HotelCode` and adds all the room prices to it. The last line removes the `HotelCode` index keys.

Comment: you have given funtastic idea about array, Big Thanks for you.